# mysql to postgresql database error

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I create a script to convert my mysql database to a postgres database

```
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
     $psql = "
    INSERT INTO subscriptions_sub (id,cust_id,tarrif_id,des,datetime_created,datetime_modified,credit,credit_limit,status,date_start,date_end,backoffice_userref,backoffice_deleted,backoffice_createdon,backoffice_createdby, backoffice_updatedon,backoffice_updatedby,backoffice_administration,backoffice_readonly,backoffice_order,backoffice_dummy)
    VALUES('" .(int) $row["subscription_id"] . "','" . (int) $row["customer_id"] . "','" . (int) $row["tariffplan_id"] . "','" . $row["description"] . "',NULLIF('" . $row["datetime_created"] . "','0000-00-00 00:00:00')::timestamp,NULLIF('" . $row["datetime_modified"] . "','0000-00-00 00:00:00')::timestamp,'" . (int) $row["credit"] . "','" . (int) $row["credit_limit"] . "','" . $row["status"] . "',NULLIF('" . $row["date_start"] . "','')::timestamp,NULLIF('" . $row["date_end"] . "','')::timestamp,'" . (int) $row["backoffice_userref"] . "','" . (int) $row["backoffice_deleted"] . "',NULLIF('" . $row["backoffice_createdon"] . "','0000-00-00 00:00:00')::timestamp,'" . (int) $row["backoffice_createdby"] . "',NULLIF('" . $row["backoffice_updatedon"] . "','0000-00-00 00:00:00')::timestamp,'" . (int) $row["backoffice_updatedby"] . "','" . (int) $row["backoffice_administration"] . "','" . (int) $row["backoffice_readonly"] . "','" . (int) $row["backoffice_order"] . "','" . (int) $row["backoffice_dummy"] . "');
    ";
    print_r($row);
    $ret = pg_query($db, $psql);
    if(!$ret){
        echo pg_last_error($db);
    } else {
        echo "Records created succesfully\n";
    }
```

When I run it I get this error:
invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "" in /home/ruud/Database2.php on line 38
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""root@149-210-204-94:/home/ruud#

datetime_created and datetime_modified are from type TIMESTAMP
date_start and date_end are from type DATE
backoffice_createon and backoffice_update on are from type DATETIME

I cant seem to find out where I'm making a error.

Comment: the error is pretty much self-explanatory.

Comment: I know it doesnt like "" as timestamp but I though I fixed that by using NULLIF(...)::timestamp. I'm still learning this so some help would be appriciated.

Comment: Why is my *Spidey sense* tingling here? You're using `mysqli_` functions with postgresql? `num_rows` that is mysqli. postgresql's equivalent is `pg_num_rows` http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-num-rows.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php for `fetch_assoc`. Plus, we have no idea which API you're using to connect with. Sorry, but I will have to pass on answering this question.